# Access Html element from ko.computed

Tags: javascript, html, dom, knockout.js

Is it possible to access bound element from ko.computed function?

Something like this pseudo code (simplified for clarity):

```
<h1 id="id1" data-bind="visible: myComputed">
<h1 id="id2" data-bind="visible: myComputed">
<h1 id="id3" data-bind="visible: myComputed">
```

...

```
self.myComputed = ko.computed(function(){
        return <BOUND_ELEMNT>.id == 'id2';
    });
```

Resulting in only the second element showing.

Note: I'm aware I can have a separate computed for every element, but it is not possible in my case.

EDIT:

Ok - I'll give a more accurate example. The following is similar to what I have:

```
<section id="id1" data-bind="visible: myComputed1">A lot of code</section>
<section id="id2" data-bind="visible: myComputed2">different lots of code</section>
<section id="id3" data-bind="visible: myComputed3">Other lots of code</section>
```

...

```
// This field's value changes over time (between 'id1', 'id2' and 'id3').
// Some complex logic changes this field,
// and as a result only one h1 is showing at a time.
self.myField = ko.observable();
self.myComputed1 = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.myField() == 'id1';
    });
self.myComputed2 = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.myField() == 'id2';
    });
self.myComputed3 = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.myField() == 'id3';
    });
```

This is an ugly violation of the DRY principle, and I would like to find a way to refactor it. The pseudo code above may solve it, but I'm open for suggestions...

Comment: Can you expand a little what are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to have only one computed? Is it required to have a computed at all? Can't you just have a function where your pass the id?

Comment: I has to be a computed. I need it to update dynamically when the viewModel state changes (the example shows a static check without dependencies just for clarity).

Comment: Usually it is a bad sign if you want to access the bound element inside your viewmodel. But without knowing exactly your goal it is hard to help. Probably you will need to create your own binding handler. Or you can use the `$elemenet` binding context variable with a function: http://jsfiddle.net/dL5Zy/1/

Comment: Ad the edit: You should tell us *why* (you think) you need three `h1` elements. From your example it doesn't seem useful, you can just have *one* `h1` element and have a `data-bind` of `attr: {id: myField}`, and forget about the `visible` binding altogether.

Comment: If this is your only logic in your computeds you can just inline them: `<h1 id="id1" data-bind="visible: myField() == 'id1'"><h1 id="id2" data-bind="visible: myField() == 'id2'">`...

Comment: @Jeroen - I shouldn't tell you why, because is it a simplified pseudo code example. They are really <section> tags with a lot of stuff in them. I just didn't want to write down my entire code.

Comment: @nemesv - Thanks for the answer, but inlining the code is quite worse than my current solution, because it  still violates DRY and it is inline in the html...

Comment: @seldary Have you checked my previous fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/dL5Zy/1/

Answer (score 3):

You've created a short, simplified example, which is normally great. However, it feels like you've introduced an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) instead. As such, this answer may or may not be helpful.

You're trying to introduce a dependency on the *View* in your *ViewModel*. It should be the other way around! Something like this would make more sense:

```
<h1 data-bind="visible: myComputed, attr { id: myId }"></h1>
```

Note the use of the [attr binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) to set the id. Your ViewModel should be constructed accordingly:

```
var activeHeaderId = 'id2';

var viewModel = function(id) {
    var self = this;

    self.myId = ko.observable(id);

    self.myComputed = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.myId() === activeHeaderId;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed it isn't helpful... I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm leaving my other answer as an answer to the first bit of the question, maybe it'll help other users stumbling upon this question.

The question in the update is:

> This is an ugly violation of the DRY principle, and I would like to find a way to refactor it.

OP indicates in comments that answers focussing on the given example are preferred. The sample code can be easily refactored such that it doesn't violate DRY anymore. (PS. I still think the "why" behind wanting this structure is very important, but that doesn't prevent me from answering the question in the context of the given sample.)

---

### Method 1 - One `h1` in the View - One item in the ViewModel

Use the following View:

```html
<h1 data-bind="attr: {id: myField}">
```

With this ViewModel:

```
self.myField = ko.observable();
```

Very DRY, functionally almost equivalent (except that the other 2 `h1` elements aren't just invisible, they're not even in the DOM).

---

### Method 2 - Multiple `h1`s in the View - Multiple items in the ViewModel

Refactor the View to a list structure (see note 4 in the [foreach binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)):

```html
<!-- ko foreach: items -->
<h1 data-bind="attr: {id: myId}, 
               text: itemName, 
               visible: $root.currentItem().myId() === myId()">
</h1>
<!-- /ko -->
```

With the following ViewModel:

```
var item = function(nr) {
    this.itemName = ko.observable("Item number " + nr);
    this.myId = ko.observable("id" + nr);
}

var viewModel = function() {
    this.items = ko.observableArray([new item(1), new item(2), new item(3)]);
    this.currentItem = ko.observable();
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6PnYN/) for a demo.

---

### Method 3 - One `h1` in the View - Multiple items in the ViewModel

With this method you use the list like setup from method 2, but only render the currentitem. The View utilizes the [`with` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html):

```html
<!-- ko with: currentItem -->
<h1 data-bind="attr: {id: myId}, text: itemName"></h1>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The ViewModel is the same as in method 2. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qa5NA/) for a demo.

Comment: I'm really just trying to get an answer without posting lots of code. I've changed the <h1> tags to <section> tags to indicate that **deleting** some of them isn't an option, so as your other proposed methods. I appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom binding handler that uses your observable to trigger the visibility.  Something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.idVisible = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var idUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if(idUnwrapped == $(element).attr('id'))
        {
            $(element).show();
        }
        else
        {
            $(element).hide();
        }
    }
};
```

Change your HTML:

```
<h1 id="id1" data-bind="idVisible: headerId">Header 1</h1>
<h1 id="id2" data-bind="idVisible: headerId">Header 2</h1>
<h1 id="id3" data-bind="idVisible: headerId">Header 3</h1>
```

And a sample view model:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.headerId = ko.observable('id1');
}
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Here's a jsFiddle with a demo that changes the headerId after two seconds: http://jsfiddle.net/psteele/cq9GU/