# Animate element in observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to animate an element from an observable array.

I'm not adding or removing items from the observableArray.

Considering the following jsfiddle, I would like to call the animateFirstElement function and highlight the planet 'Mercury'

I can easily get the item. But I don't know how to get it's corresponding HTML element:

```
this.animateFirstElement = function() {
    alert(this.planets()[0].name);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8k8V5/2644/

Comment: Accessing and manipulating HTML elements directly is what Knockout is trying to prevent you from doing. Your views should be dependent on your view models, not the other way around. Consider using a custom binding that binds to a property in your view model to trigger the animation.

Comment: Here's a similar question with a great answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296774/access-html-element-from-ko-computed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126812/knockout-js-get-dom-object-associated-with-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would second what @CrimsonChris said in comments, though it is fairly simple either way. Knockout by default passes the parameters `data, event` to any bindings on the view. So for example if you wanted to highlight a planet when the user clicks it, you could do:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { 'class': 'planet ' + type }, 
                text: name, 
                click: highlightElement"> </div>
```

And in `highlightElement`:

```
function highlightElement(data, e) {
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  myHighlightFunction(target);
}
```

If you want to trigger actions from the parent context, you can stick a good ol' `id` attribute to the container, eg `planet-list`, and animate additions/ removals with jQuery outside of Knockout, eg:

```
this.removeFirstElement = function() {
    var target = document.getElementById('planet-list'),
        planet = target.children[0];
    $(planet).slideUp(400,function() { self.planets.shift(); });
};
```

You can also do it *within* knockout, for example by building a custom binding that [controls descendant bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html), or you could use `planetsToShow.subscribe` to animate accordingly when the array has become smaller/ bigger. Note that in the view you can perfectly pass `$element` to a function, or `$index` (as in my tests below)

I've made some changes to your fiddle, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/8k8V5/2652/

Answer (score 1):

The key is not to work against knockout. Your viewmodel never needs to know the HTML elements that are used to render it.

If you want to influence visibility of your items, introduce a `visible` property on your viewmodel and make your view react to changes in this property.  If necessary create custom bindings that handle the animation itself - I've created `fadeVisible` and `slideVisible` bindings below.

The following uses a separate `Planet` viewmodel and a subscription to the `typeToShow` property.

```js
function Planet(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = data.name;
    self.type = data.type;
    self.visible = ko.observable(true);
}
Planet.create = function (data) {
    return new Planet(data);
};

function Planets(data) {
    var self = this;
    
    self.planets = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.planets, Planet.create)); 
    self.typeToShow = ko.observable("all");
    self.displayAdvancedOptions = ko.observable(true);
 
    self.addPlanet = function(name, type) {
        self.planets.push(new Planet({
            name: name || "New planet",
            type: type || "rock"
        }));
    };
    
    self.typeToShow.subscribe(function (type) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.planets(), function(planet) {
            planet.visible(type === "all" || ko.unwrap(planet.type) === type);
        });
    });
}

ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor(),
            visible = ko.unwrap(value);
        $(element).toggle(visible);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor(),
            visible = ko.unwrap(value);
        $(element)[visible ? "fadeIn" : "fadeOut"]();
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.slideVisible = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor(),
            visible = ko.unwrap(value);
        $(element).toggle(visible);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor(),
            visible = ko.unwrap(value);
        $(element)[visible ? "slideDown" : "slideUp"]();
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new Planets({
    planets: [
        { name: "Mercury", type: "rock"},
        { name: "Venus", type: "rock"},
        { name: "Earth", type: "rock"},
        { name: "Mars", type: "rock"},
        { name: "Jupiter", type: "gasgiant"},
        { name: "Saturn", type: "gasgiant"},
        { name: "Uranus", type: "gasgiant"},
        { name: "Neptune", type: "gasgiant"},
        { name: "Pluto", type: "rock"}
    ]
}));
```

```css
body { font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; }
.liveExample { padding: 1em; background-color: #EEEEDD; border: 1px solid #CCC; max-width: 655px; }
.liveExample input { font-family: Arial; }
.liveExample b { font-weight: bold; }
.liveExample p { margin-top: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; }
.liveExample select[multiple] { width: 100%; height: 8em; }
.liveExample h2 { margin-top: 0.4em; }

.planet { background-color: #AAEECC; padding: 0.25em; border: 1px solid silver; margin-bottom: 0.5em; font-size: 0.75em; }
.planet.rock { background-color: #EECCAA; }
.liveExample input { margin: 0 0.3em 0 1em; }

li { list-style-type: disc; margin-left: 20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class='liveExample'> 
    <h2>Planets</h2>
 
    <p data-bind='fadeVisible: displayAdvancedOptions'>
        Show:
        <label><input type='radio' name="type" value='all' data-bind='checked: typeToShow' />All</label>
        <label><input type='radio' name="type" value='rock' data-bind='checked: typeToShow' />Rocky planets</label>
        <label><input type='radio' name="type" value='gasgiant' data-bind='checked: typeToShow' />Gas giants</label>
    </p>
     
    <div data-bind='foreach: planets'>
        <div data-bind='attr: { "class": "planet " + type }, text: name, slideVisible: visible'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Animating the first planet is so trivial now that I did not bother to implement it.

Comment: Can you explain how to animate the first planet when I click a button? That was the original question :) Thks

Comment: Look at the last sentence in my answer. Then understand my answer. Then it will come to you.

Comment: Sorry but I really didn't get it. Maybe I'm missing what you're doing here: $(element)[visible ? "fadeIn" : "fadeOut"]();

Comment: Maybe, but this the core of the solution lies somewhere else. Read the first sentence in the second paragraph of my answer again. (I'm not going to tell you what to do, I want that you realize it yourself. The learning effect will be so much higher this way.)

Comment: (`$(element)[visible ? "fadeIn" : "fadeOut"]();` evaluates to `$(element).fadeIn();` or `$(element).fadeOut();`,  depending on the value of `visible`. You can index into object properties with square brackets in JavaScript.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:
Change lines:

```
<div data-bind='attr: { "class": name + "_" + type }, text: name'> </div>
this.animateFirstElement = function() {
    $("." + this.planets()[0].name + "_" + this.planets()[0].type).toggle();
};
```